# Resizeable JButton in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, boxlayout

I have the following code:

```
  public void showFrame() {
    var frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    var panel = frame.getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    panel.add(new Button("Button 1"));
    panel.add(new Button("Button 2"));
    panel.add(new Button("Button 3"));
    panel.add(new Button("Button 4"));
    panel.add(new JButton("Button 5"));

    frame.setSize(200, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

Which generates the following form:

[image: rendered form]

Buttons 1 to 4 (AWT buttons) resize together with the window. But button 5 (Swing button) behaves differently.

I would like button 5 to also be resizeable. I believe I'm missing something. Is there a simple way to make button 5 resizeable?

Comment: you can do a setSize() and redraw it.

Comment: Why are you using native AWT buttons?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I'm just using them as example for the desired behaviour. I'm planning to replace them with Swing buttons.

Comment: If your button `JPanel` uses a `GridLayout`, the `JButtons` will resize with the `JPanel`.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thanks, it is working as intended now.

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for the response, I found GridLayout better for my case compared to setSize()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like button 5 to also be resizeable. I believe I'm missing something. Is there a simple way to make button 5 resizeable?

`BoxLayout` respects the minimum/maximum sizes of components.

By default for a JButton those sizes are set to the preferred size.

If you want the button to grow you need to override the `getMaximumSize()` method of the button to return a dimension for the maximum that you want.

As suggested in the comments, an easier solution is to use a `GridLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, GridLayout seems better to my case than getMaximumSize()